# Eleventy with git submodule for private content?

Tags: git, eleventy

I'm trying to use Eleventy and Netlify to create a website with both public and private content, with the latter requiring authentication as in the [11ty/demo-eleventy-serverless-auth](https://github.com/11ty/demo-eleventy-serverless-oauth) sample project. I'd like the public and private content to be in separate public and private git repositories, so that anyone can contribute to the former without being able to see the latter.

I've gotten quite close by using a git submodule for the private content, but I'm having trouble preserving the `--watch` automatic rebuilding and Browsersync functionality. The problem is with the `input` directory, which needs the content files from both repositories.

Initially I tried to copy the private content prior to the `build` and `start` commands in `package.json`, but that only gets run once at the beginning of `npm run dev`, and does not get re-run when the content changes.

Then I found the [`eleventy.before` event](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/events/#eleventy.before), which I hoped to use with `fs-extra.copySync` to move the files from the private repo into my `input` directory.

**The problem, however, is that the `input` is also being watched, so the copy triggers *another* build and thus an infinite loop.** Some things I've explored:

- Deleting the `input` directory in the callback for the `eleventy.after` event, which I hoped would be safe since `output` exists already, but this seems to break the entire site.

  - Maybe it breaks the site because the [Serverless plugin](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/plugins/serverless/) no longer has files to use as input? To fix that I tried to specify a different `inputDir` for the plugin with a *second, unwatched* copy of the content, but that it didn't help.
  - Or maybe it breaks the site because the `fs-extra.rmSync` also triggers a rebuild, but now there's no content.
- I wanted to try a synchronous, rather than `async` method in the `eleventy.before` handler, in case there was a race condition triggering the infinite loop. I experimented with `eleventyConfig.setWatchThrottleWaitTime` to simulate this, but it didn't help, perhaps because that option is now unsupported.
- I could remove the `input` directory as a watch target and only look at my two pre-merge content directories... but that functionality doesn't seem to exist.
- I tried adding the combined `input` directory to `.eleventyignore` in `eleventy:after` and removing it in `eleventy:before`, with the goal to make it only visible during the build and otherwise not able to trigger changes, but that didn't work either.

The repo I'm working with is [here](https://github.com/PatchworkAutomata/website). Is there something I'm missing, or do I need an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [a suggestion from Aankhen#6432](https://discord.com/channels/741017160297611315/974757501675397190/974779679649173504) in the [11ty Discord](https://www.11ty.dev/blog/discord/), I solved this by preserving the modification times of unchanged files.

In the `eleventy.before` event handler I used [`klaw-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/klaw-sync) to create a list of all of the files I needed to copy. Then for each path, after confirming the source and destination with `fs.existsSync`, I used `fs.statSync` to compare their `mtimeMs` last modification times. I then only perform the `fs.copySync` if the destination is older than the source (or is missing).

This resolved the infinite loop, but revealed another issue present only on Netlify: the serverless function for my dynamic pages had just a subset of my project's files. First, it was missing the private content directory, triggering an error in my `eleventy.before` handler when there was nothing to copy. Fortunately, it *did* have the merged content directory, and that already contained my private content from a previous build. The merged content directory did not, however, have the `_includes` folder from the public content directory, which caused the serverless function to fail when rendering the templates.

So, rather than create the merged content directory at build time and copy in everything from the public and private content directories, I just kept the `_includes` directory there from the beginning. That means the `eleventy.before` event handler is only copying `.md` files. This avoids this second problem and is maybe better anyway, in case I later want to move the public content into a separate repo as well.